# Red Black Tree deletion of root

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, red-black-tree

My red black tree algorithm for deletion works well unless I delete the root. Where only one of the child is saved and the rest of the tree values are lost.

I believe the problem is in the `removeNode()` method in the lines where

```
if (remove == root)
{
    root = child;
}
```

Here are the methods used for deletion:

```
//Searching for value to remove
public void removeSearch(int value)
{
    RedBlackNode rt = root;
    while (rt != sentinel)
    {
        int compare = value.CompareTo(rt.getItem());
        if (compare == 0)
        {
            if (rt.getLeft() == sentinel || rt.getRight() == sentinel)
            {
                removeNode(rt);
            }
            else
            {
                RedBlackNode successor = inOrderSuccessor(rt);
                rt.setItem(successor.getItem());
                removeNode(rt);                        
            }
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            rt = rt.getChild(compare);
            //return true;
        }
    }
}

protected RedBlackNode inOrderSuccessor(RedBlackNode node)
{
    RedBlackNode descendant = node.getRight();

        while (descendant.getLeft() != sentinel)
        {
            descendant = descendant.getLeft();
        }
    return descendant;
}

protected void removeNode(RedBlackNode remove)
{
    count -= 1;
    RedBlackNode child;
    if (remove.getLeft() != sentinel)
    {
        child = remove.getLeft();
    }
    else
    {
        child = remove.getRight();
    }
    linkParentAndChild(remove.getParent(), child, comparison(remove, remove.getParent()));

    if(remove==root)
    {
        root = child;
    }
    if(remove.isBlack())
    {
        DeleteFix(child);
    }
}

protected void DeleteFix(RedBlackNode node)
{
    while((node!=root)&&(node.isBlack()))
    {
        RedBlackNode parent = node.getParent();
        int compare = comparison(node, parent);
        RedBlackNode sibling = parent.getChild(-compare);
        if(sibling.isRed())
        {
            sibling.setBlack();
            parent.setRed();
            rotate(-compare, parent);
            sibling = node.getParent().getChild(-compare);
        } 
        if(sibling.hasTwoBlackChildren())
        {
            sibling.setRed();
            node = node.getParent();
        }else
        {
            if(sibling.getChild(-compare).isBlack())
            {
                sibling.getChild(compare).setBlack();
                sibling.setRed();
                rotate(compare, sibling);
                sibling = parent.getChild(-compare);
            }
            sibling.setColour(parent.getColour());
            parent.setBlack();
            sibling.getChild(-compare).setBlack();
            rotate(-compare, parent);
            node = root;
        }
    }
    node.setBlack();
}
```

Any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Walk through this with me:

```
if (remove.getLeft() != sentinel)
{
    child = remove.getLeft();
}
else
{
    child = remove.getRight();
}
linkParentAndChild(remove.getParent(), child, comparison(remove, remove.getParent()));

if(remove==root)
{
    root = child;
}
```

First, assume `remove == root`. Then, assume the root's left child is  `sentinel`. The first if branch evaluates to false, the `else` clause is executed, and `child` becomes the right node. Then, you try to get the parent of the root (presumably `null` but I have no idea) and link that to the right node... I guess that this ends up doing nothing but I don't know for sure because you didn't provide that method. Then, you replace the root with `child`, which is the right node, and because `linkParentAndChild` was (presumably) passed in `null` there was no way to recover the left node, so you clobber it and it's gone. If the left node isn't `sentinel`, then the process is exactly the same but you'll keep the left side instead of the right.

Hopefully that should clear up why it happens. I'm not going to tell you how to solve it for two reasons:

1. This is almost certainly homework, no one implements a red-black tree unless it's for homework.
2. I don't really remember the implementation details of red-black trees very well, mostly due to reason number 1.

Good luck solving it!

Comment: Yes in fact I was mistaken and when I'm continuing to debug, the root is always excluding the right subtree of the chosen node to delete. And this is happening throughout not only in the root

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a slight hint of what needs to be done? I'm not sure whether I'm missing out a lot of information from my methods

Comment: I don't know enough about your code to help you with broad debugging like that but it sounds like your comparison to `sentinel` isn't working. If you haven't defined an `Equals()` method on `RedBlackNode` it will test equality on reference identity (I think) so unless you're using exactly the same `sentinel` everywhere that comparison might not work. Or it might be something else, I have no idea. You'd be better off (and safer) talking to a classmate or visiting your instructor's office hours.

Comment: This was solved. The following day I debugged it and didn't notice that I was missing another case were the left and right child are populated. Added another method findMinimum() and the root's value is changed according to the returned value.